# Push one branch to another while ignoring a file in github

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I have two branches - dev, master

dev and master both have a file called config.js but with different code lines in it.

So I want to ignore overriding the master- config.js file when I push dev to master. Kindly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is not going to be possible.  Trying to keep a file that is different between two branches that are going to have merges or cherry-picks done is not going to work.

There are some possible solutions with custom merge drivers that you can add to `.gitattributes`, but the programs that you use to perform those custom merges are not listed in the repository, and as a result GitHub and other tools don't even know what they are (nor would they use them if they did, since they don't execute arbitrary code on behalf of users).  To implement this would require a custom bot to merge all your code, and even then, this is not a recommended approach.

You'd be better off keeping both config files, just named different things, and copying the correct one into the `config.js` location (which would be ignored) with a script.  That is going to make your life a lot easier and allow you to use a normal workflow with the hosting platform of your choice.